# Should we sort the two lists and then combine, or other way round?

Tags: algorithm

If I have two lists of numbers, to be able to get a single sorted list, should I first sort the individual ones and then do a merge sort, or should I just combine the two lists into one list and then apply an efficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: Why is this tagged machine-learning?

Comment: Splitting into two lists is how most efficient sorting algorithms work ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an argument either way; it depends on many factors:

The options for lists A and B are:

1. sort(A concat B)
2. merge(sort(A), sort(B))

If A and B are both nearly sorted and similar in size, then doing something that works fast on nearly sorted lists like insert sort can be done on both.  Then you do the merge, which takes linear time, making option (2) near-linear.  But in this case, if the range of values within each list is similar, option (1) will not be good at all, leaving you with something probably O(n log n), assuming your values are not amenable to a radix or counting sort.  That is, for many sorting algorithms, longer lists hurt because data is moved over longer distances.

Now we can probably come up with cases in which option (1) is better.

However if you find that option (2) is always better in your situation, this does *not* mean that you should apply a recursive splitting and merging approach naively, since there is overhead in doing so.

But as with all questions about "which sorting approach is better" you really have to look at:

- The size of the lists
- The range (min, max) of values within the lists (since O(n) sorts can be used in certain situations)
- Whether they are nearly sorted, nearly reverse sorted, completely random or whatever
- Wheter external memory is allowed, forbidden, etc.
- Whether you are sorting in memory or sorting files
- Whether the lists are about the same size or one is much longer than the other.

In short, "it depends," but if the lists are already split and your sorting algorithm is sensitve to list length, you can get some benefit out of option (2).

Comment: The only case I can think of where (1) would be better is if nearly all elements of A are less than nearly all elements of B, and you used an algorithm like insertion sort that does well on nearly-sorted inputs.  But in that case, InsertionSortTime(A concat B) will take about as long as InsertionSortTime(A) + InsertionSortTime(B), so the improvement would only be a constant factor: the difference between merging 2 lists and concatenating 2 lists (both are O(n) operations, but the merge requires O(n) comparisons too).

Comment: +1 I also think that (2) is "almost always" better.  The merge is insensitive to the element ordering so when sorts are not O(n) like counting and radix, the sorting on the smaller lists first should, in general, help.

Answer (score 0):

If they're not already sorted, I'd just combine them and do a single sort. If it was more efficient to sort them separately and then do a merge sort, then the most efficient sorting algorithms would be built that way: arbitrarily split your list in two, sort separately and merge. But that is not the case, ergo....

Comment: Most efficient sorting algorithms (mergesort, quicksort) *are* built that way.  The exception is heapsort.  What algorithms are you thinking of?  Insertion sort?  That can be quick on nearly-sorted data, but its worst case efficiency is bad (O(n^2)).